# How to change form-select Option Select to dark mode

Tags: bootstrap-4

How do i change my css stylesheet to make the form-select dark?

```
<select class="form-select">
 <option value="1" selected>1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
 <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Your title mentions Bootstrap 5, yet you've tagged version 4. Please correct that. Don't put tags in your title. See [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the class `bg-dark` to make the background dark and `text-white` to achieve a better contrast.

```html
<select class="form-select bg-dark text-white">
 <option value="1" selected>1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
 <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `data-bs-theme="dark"` to the outer div:

```
<div data-bs-theme="dark">
    <select  class="form-select form-select-sm border-0 shadow-none">
        <option value='ENG'>ENG</option>
        <option value='HIN'>HIN</option>
        <option value='GER'>GER</option>
        <option value='FRN'>FRN</option>
    </select>
</div>
```